# CALayer content goes out of bounds - iOS

Tags: ios, transform, calayer, scale

I am trying to implement camera zoom using `CGAffinetransform`. Transform is fine, but when I scale it to a bigger size, it goes out of the frame I have assigned to the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`. I tried setting `masksToBounds` property to `YES` but it didn't help.

Can I contain it within its frame?

**Edit:**
What I want is that I can specify a specific area for the camera preview layer, if I apply scaling transform to it, (i.e., frame of preview layer gets expanded), the part of the layer outside of the specified area gets clipped.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should put the layer you are scaling inside of another layer and mask that one instead (the superlayer). The same thing works with views.

I.e. You have two views / layers: `clippingView` and `scalingView` where scalingView is the subview of clippingView and clippingView is the view that actually clips to it's bounds.

```
[clippingView addSubview:scalingView];
clippingView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

or using layers

```
[clippingLayer addSublayer:scalingLayer];
clippingLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I tried adding a separate view, (`UIImageView` because of some reason, but that shouldn't matter I suppose) and added a sublayer as the previewLayer which I was setting as the subLayer of `self.view.layer`. I set `masksToBounds' as `YES` but still it goes out of bounds

Comment: What I did was, I made a view, with the frame that I wanted the preview layer to be in. and i set its property `clipsToBounds` to YES. That was all. Doc says that all the content of the view will lie inside the specified frame if this property is set to Yes. Actually I never came across the property before now.

Answer (score 4):

You guys are all partially right I found but I wanted to clarify.

Lets say we added something like AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer to the view via `[self.view.layer addSublayer:previewLayer]`

1. [self clipsToBounds] does NOTHING until you are telling its primary layer to mask to bounds. `[self.view.layer masksToBounds];`
2. Just because your view has a frame and so does its layers DOES NOT MEAN IT HAS BOUNDS. If it doesnt have bounds then there is nothing to mask to. So do this `self.view.layer.bounds = self.view.frame`;

So heres it all together..keep in mind I did this in my own UIView class so I dont need to call self.view.

```
previewLayer.bounds = self.frame;
self.layer.bounds = self.frame;

self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
previewLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

[self setBounds:self.frame];
[self clipsToBounds];
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Even I have a custom UIView and I want to show a camera using AVFoundation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`clipsToBounds` property of the view to which I am adding the layer should have been set to `YES`.

Comment: Any reason in particular for changing the accepted answer? You are basically saying the same thing as I am.

Comment: 1) Your answer was not the accepted answer before this, probably because I didn't understand it at that time. Confused between layers and views.  
  2) Yesterday I looked at my answer, and saw that there was no accepted answer, so I accepted my own...

Comment: But now I see that yours was accepted. So, a mistake has been done.

Comment: So is that all you had to change. Im having the exact same problem. the layer gets larger than the frame itself. I setup a NSLog to verify that the views fram itself wasnt getting larger. even though I have clipsToBounds on the view set to yes, and maskstobounds set to yes on the preview layer...the preview layer is still going outside.